# git clone appears to be successful but clone directory doesn't exist

Tags: git, github

I am cloning a repo in my newly set up git environment.

when i clone a repo, it doesn't give nay error and seems repo was cloned to my local directory however it doesn't happen when i list.

Following is the snippet:

```
login2.ls5(158)$ git clone https://github.com/suyashdb/hcp2bids.git
Cloning into 'hcp2bids'...
login2.ls5(159)$ ls
mytaccscripts  test
```

What can be the possible issues in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you probably put it in you base drive. To check, open terminal and type cd. then do ls. Try going into your desktop or some place where you can easily access.